# Open Gmail draft created in Gmail API in browser window

Tags: hyperlink, google-api, gmail, gmail-api

Per this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24462562/can-i-get-a-url-link-to-a-gmail-draft-using-the-gmail-api) I should be able to go directly to a Gmail draft message, created using the Gmail REST API, using a hyperlink formatted like:

```
https://mail.google.com/mail/#drafts?compose={ThreadId}
```

However, it's not working. The thread ID I get as a response to my Gmail API call does not open the draft message created. What's really strange is when I open the draft from Gmail (that I created using the API) the thread ID DOES match for a split second in the URL then changes.

How does one open directly to a draft message utilizing the message.threadId? I'd like it to be a pop out message as well and should be possible per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24548210/is-there-an-url-to-open-the-gmail-compose-window-with-a-specific-message-id-in-f) but getting the draft to show at all is my first priority.

[image: Gmail id hyperlink to draft]

Comment: Gmail devs: Is there no way to open a draft message in a browser? Per the API documentation: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/send I should be able to use the "immutable ID of the draft" but how can I do that if it changes? Is this a bug in the API?

Comment: I haven't received an answer to my initial question, so I'll rephrase it: What is the purpose of returning the draft's Thread ID if it can't be used? It's returned from the API call in JSON format. Is there a use for it? If not, seems like unnecessary overhead. Even if the thread ID change every time a draft is open/edited, I'm just looking for a way to open it initially, immediately after I create it using the Gmail API. Thanks in advance for a solution or explanation.

Comment: This works: `"https://mail.google.com/mail/ca/u/0/#drafts/" + draftResponse.getMessage().getThreadId()` 

Credits: @Chris Wood from this SO question https://stackoverflow.com/q/50124112/455449 (see comment below)

Comment: ... and, the purpose of threadId is quite different - it binds together all individual messages that are related in a thread (supported by the UI); by observation, it seems to equal messageId of the first message in a thread.

Answer (score 2):

The thread id/message id of a draft are not stable. That is, they change everytime the draft is edited/saved. The only thing that is stable is the draft id, however, this is not available in the gmail ui.

Comment: I've created an Excel application where my client sends multiple, mail merge, type of emails using Gmail API (oAuth2) through VBA. Before sending a lot of emails I want them to have the ability to preview exactly how the HTML formatted email will look (they create it using text only & html code in an Excel form). There is a preview button and I want it to open the Gmail draft. They only need to view it, I'm not concerned with them editing and re-saving the draft. I just want them to see what it would look like before sending it.

Answer (score 2):

The [Users.drafts.create API call](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/create) returns a [User.drafts resource](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts#resource) containing the draft ID. The draft ID is not the same thing as a message or thread ID, but you can then call [Users.drafts.get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/get) or [Users.drafts.list](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/list), both of which will let you correlate the draft ID to a thread ID and message ID.