# GMail Link to Draft

Tags: gmail-api

I've created a Gmail draft by using the API. I got the folowing data:

```
{
 "id": "r-5124711675755XXXXXXX",
 "message": {
 "id": "1660c28d2XXXXXXXX",
 "threadId": "1660c28d2XXXXXXXX",
 "labelIds": [
 "DRAFT"
 ]
}
```

}

Now i wanna open my newly created draft in my browser by calling the URL:

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#drafts?compose=CXXXXXXXXXXXXXxxxXXXXXXXXXXXXxxxXzrTZcJkDlnZdSMRLCMqkPfsVFRxrxPmNjhNScgV

But where i get the value compose=CXXXXXXXXXXXXXxxxXXXXXXXXXXXXxxxXzrTZcJkDlnZdSMRLCMqkPfsVFRxrxPmNjhNScgV??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the **current** Gmail UI, the id seems to be the draft message ID returned by the API.

From your example, the compose URL would be:

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#drafts?compose=1660c28d2XXXXXXXX

NOTE:  I don't see anywhere in the docs where this is defined/supported behavior.  It may work with the current Gmail UI, and then break with a future version.

Here is some information about the **new** Gmail UI:  [How does a Gmail message Id or ThreadId map to the new Gmail UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50124112/how-does-a-gmail-message-id-or-threadid-map-to-the-new-gmail-ui)

Comment: This appears to NOT currently work as of this writing.  Using the format:

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but you can simply do the following concatenation:

`https://mail.google.com/mail/#all/<threadId>`

This will open the draft's thread from which you can edit it.