# new gmail uri messageID

Tags: c#, gmail, gmail-api

I used the gmail api to create an email draft and composed it with an uri where the messageId was included directly to the browser.
Also I've read an email content by reading the specific email uri.
These uris looked like https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/**1678b2980327a67e**.

But with the new gmail design the messageId has changed and with the actual gmail api version there is no way to get these new messageIds.
The new uris look like https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox/**KfcrxvzLTCBApkvlFsCKLHbsGrZhGjv**

Is there a workaround for this problem or is there something planned for the future?

Comment: Possible duplicate:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50124112/how-does-a-gmail-message-id-or-threadid-map-to-the-new-gmail-ui

Comment: I need a solution for c# and not for ruby

Comment: The duplicate link I sent above is language-agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to encode/decode the gmail URL thread id.

However, you can search by rfc22msgid then get the thread id using the gmail api.

Step by step example:

- URL of thread in gmail
  https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/FMfcgxwChcltfVrZXGFCXZcxslFgTfDz
- click "Show Original"
- Copy the Message-ID e.g 5d222026.1c69fb81.f6df7.74d5@mx.google.com
- verify search query works and returns thread:
  rfc822msgid:5d222026.1c69fb81.f6df7.74d5@mx.google.com
- same query but using gmail api
  `threadsResponse, err := srv.Users.Threads.List(user).Q("rfc822msgid:5d222026.1c69fb81.f6df7.74d5@mx.google.com").Do()`
- that will return the backend thread-id & message-id